# How to detect certain face on the photo

Tags: language-agnostic, face-recognition

I was just having a nap and then that crazy idea came into my head. Here it is.

We have 2 different photos with face in each. How can we detect if there is the same person on that two photos?

Is it possible to do that? If yes, can I do it with Java or PHP? What the way to do it? Any ideas? Maybe each face has a "algorithm" or something which could help us?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you find an effective solution, I would imagine the CIA has a job for you.

Comment: Java or PHP is the least of your worries.  Google 'face recognition.'

Comment: @jamietre Um, google piscasa has this feature builtin.

Comment: Right, google, the same people who China was trying to hack to steal their technology :) No I realize that there are some implementations out there, but as far as "how do I do this" questions go, it's kind of like asking "how do I go to mars."

Comment: @jamietre : I was just asking where should I begin, I was not asking for a code. Thank you. :)

Comment: You begin with googling the subject, follow that with billions of dollars in venture capital and decades of R&D, and end with SkyNet determining that you are no longer necessary and killing you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an trivial solution (and cannot be covered in an SO answer); you can start by [reading papers on facial recognition](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Facial+Recognition&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=801). If this is something you really want to do, be prepared to read a lot of background information first before you actually start writing code. This subject matter is the basis for a lot of people's doctoral and masters theses. In this case, language is not as important as the *algorithm*. Also be prepared for **lots of math**. At the very least, you'll learn something cool. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was freelancing a very similar task. Its not fun. almost impossible to build face recognition - face detection is easy, recognition is the tough part... the algorithm is generally a guarded secret as I've seen.

But I did find this: http://face.com/

Face recognition API. Feed it data, it feeds you names and details you've previously fed it. You have the ability to check to see if a face exists.

If you make a lot of requests or start working at an enterprise level - they charge.

Answer (score 1):

The language doesn't really matter as long as it has the tools to do number crunching on the image data.  Facial recognition is too big of topic for a forum post like this.  I would just google "facial recognition algorithms".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that this is not trivial.

1. detect a face in both photos
2. normalize the facial data
3. compare the data to see if they match